# Failing VBA with Rs 232 com port

Tags: json, vba, ms-access

I need your help to spot why the code below failed to run or connect to RS 232/VBA Ms Access. First and foremost, below is the specification of the machine provided by the Taxman:
1.      Configuration for the serial port is as follows:

```
"baud=115200
parity=N
data=8
stop=1
```

"
there is no restriction on the write/read data rate
2.      we leave the port open 24 hours service. We suggest you use this approach. Leave the port open.
3.      Every information returned by the ESD during invoice signing request should be printed on the invoice.

End of instruction guide by the Taxman

The assembled code below is in 4 stages, I will explain all the stages in details below:

(1)

```
CommOpen(intPortID
```

:
This is the first stage of interaction with the machine, the code here is used to open the gadget or initialise if like it that way. I have no problem with this.

(2)

```
CommWrite(intPortID, strData)
```

:
The second stage is to now write the data into the port. What I have done here is to put the converted Json data into a string first as follows:

```
strData = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(transaction, Whitespace:=3)
```

Then assign that Json data into string as below:

```
lngStatus = CommWrite(intPortID, strData)
```

(3)      Finally, I have now put an error handling code see below

**END OF SENDING DATA WITH JSON FORMAT**

**Full code below:**

```
Dim json As String
    Dim intPortID As Integer ' Ex. 1, 2, 3, 4 for COM1 - COM4
    Dim lngStatus As Long
    Dim strError  As String
    Dim strData   As String
    Dim lngSize As Long
    ' Initialize Communications
    lngStatus = CommOpen(intPortID, "COM" & CStr(intPortID), _
        "baud=115200 parity=N data=8 stop=1")

    If lngStatus <> 0 Then
    ' Handle error.
        lngStatus = CommGetError(strError)
    MsgBox "COM Error: " & strError
    End If


    ' Set modem control lines.
    lngStatus = CommSetLine(intPortID, LINE_RTS, True)
    lngStatus = CommSetLine(intPortID, LINE_DTR, True)

    ' Write data to serial port.
    strData = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(transaction, Whitespace:=3)
    lngSize = Len(strData)
    lngStatus = CommWrite(intPortID, strData)
    If lngStatus <> lngSize Then
    ' Handle error.
    End If
Call CmdReadWrite_Click
Exit_CmdConertJson_Click:
Exit Sub
Err_Handler:
Resume Exit_CmdConertJson_Click
End Sub
```

**Reading Data Code**

This where I have BIG problems, see issues below:
(1)      I’m required to leave the code open without limitation:

```
lngStatus = CommRead(intPortID, strData, 14400)
```

The above limitation is not required (14400) it must be open, but if do not put something it always gives an error request for a missing parameter.
(2)      I’m not very sure whether the code below functions properly, someone helped me here sometime back, but I cannot remember what was discussed about it I have a lot of ?????????? here:

```
ReadDataFromSerialDevice (DataRead, 4)
```

(3)      I want to now store the received data from the gadget into table called ("tblEfdReceipts"), but here, that is where another challenge is Im completely lost here, I have put a code below just on try and error basis, can someone help me here????????????

```
StoreData DataObject
```

(4)      Because the received data need to be attached with the sent invoice details and signed by the Taxman server, I have now attempted to attach the actual invoice, see below:

```
rs![INVID] = Me.InvoiceID
```

Summary

The data cannot be sent and signed up from the Taxman server as long the above issues mentioned above cannot be resolved. I feel the major problem is on the receiving side and the parameter limitation. Kindly see how you can help on this.
The worst case scenario is that now we have to wait for another 90 days to have this software retested due to a huge number of people lining up for the same certification with taxman.

**Full code for receiving**

```
Private Sub CmdReadWrite_Click()
Dim DataRead As String
  Dim DataObject As Object

  If ReadDataFromSerialDevice (DataRead, 4) Then
    ' Call to your JSON library to parse it.
    Set DataObject = ParseJson(DataRead)
    StoreData DataObject
    MsgBox "Data have written in the contact table", vbExclamation, "Please proceed"
    Set DataObject = Nothing
  End If

End Sub


Private Function ReadDataFromSerialDevice (ByRef ADataRead As String, APortID As Long) As Boolean

  Dim lngStatus As Long
  Dim strData As String
  Dim intPortID As Integer

  ReadDataFromSerialDevice = False
   lngStatus = CommRead(intPortID, strData, 14400)
    If lngStatus > 0 Then
    ADataRead = strData
    ReadDataFromSerialDevice = True
  End If

  lngStatus = CommSetLine(intPortID, LINE_RTS, False)
  lngStatus = CommSetLine(intPortID, LINE_DTR, False)
  ' Close communications.
    Call CommClose(intPortID)
End Function

Private Sub StoreData(ADataObject As Object)

  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
  Dim item As Object

  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblEfdReceipts")
  For Each item In ADataObject
    rs.AddNew
            rs![TPIN] = item("TPIN")
            rs![TaxpayerName] = item("TaxpayerName")
            rs![Address] = item("Address")
            rs![ESDTime] = item("ESDTime")
            rs![TerminalID] = item("TerminalID")
            rs![InvoiceCode] = item("InvoiceCode")
            rs![InvoiceNumber] = item("InvoiceCode")
            rs![FiscalCode] = item("FiscalCode")
            rs![TalkTime] = item("TalkTime")
            rs![Operator] = item("Operator")
            rs![Taxlabel] = item("TaxItems")("TaxLabel")
            rs![CategoryName] = item("TaxItems")("CategoryName")
            rs![Rate] = item("TaxItems")("Rate")
            rs![TaxAmount] = item("TaxItems")("TaxAmount")
            rs![VerificationUrl] = item("TaxItems")("VerificationUrl")
            rs![INVID] = Me.InvoiceID
            rs.Update
  Next item

  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image]

This error messages come up after assigning intPortID to (intPortID = 2) and StoreData DataObject to StoreData (DataObject)

Comment: How far does your code work? Is the port initialization working? To me it can't, as you don't give a value to `intPortID` before calling `CommOpen(intPortID...)`

Comment: its comopen out of range error no. 9

Comment: Is it okay if I give it a value like this assuming this the port to opened (intPortID = 2)

Comment: Well, you MUST give a value to `intPortID`, e.g. `intPortID = 2` before you call `CommOpen(intPortID...)`. A variable of type integer is initialized to 0 as default, and that is not a valid comm port number. And you must of course give the number of the comm port that you are using for your connection.